# ESPN Api Integration issue

Tags: iphone, ios, espn

I am implementing espn api, but having some issue, most api gives me this response.

```
{"timestamp" :"2013-02-25T11:19:02Z","message" :"This action is forbidden for the requested resource at your permission level. Please review the documentation for account level access.","status" :"error","code" :403}
```

---

I am using this api [Espn MLB Standing](http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/standings?apikey=mkygnjtr7tz5cv4ea892s9f6)

I want to know that where to review the documentation, i is there any need to purchase some api or anything else?

**[EDIT]**

One more thing there is `?apikey=:yourkey` , so this key is same for all user or we have to get this according to user login.

Comment: this http://developer.espn.com/docs link tells accessibility level of the espn api .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong **apikey** or there is some issue in your URL query.

Your app will have a unique **apikey**. This key is same for all users who are using the app.

You should get a apikey by registering to their site and use it for development purpose.

Comment: registered and got the api=mkygnjtr7tz5cv4ea892s9f6

Answer (score 0):

My rep doesn't allowing commenting, but I thought I'd add the following here:

- A small amount of ESPN API data is free, but much requires payment.
- You probably don't want to publicly share your personal API key for security reasons.
- Go to http://developer.espn.com/io-docs and plug in your API key and use the GUI to generate an API call/response.  It's a good way to see a valid, working syntax that you can then drop into your app and edit as necessary.